# KnockoutJS erratic behaviour on iPad (iOS 8.3)

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've come across some unusual behavior when using KnockoutJS on iOS.

The structure of the page has a person object with an array of customers. Each customer has an array of actions. The person object also has an a ko.computed that returns the action from all the customers that meet certain criteria.

If I add a new action to one of the customers then it will be added to the ko.computed but part of the page will disappear even though they are not bound to any observable. If I touch the screen then they will reappear. This happens if I use a throttle on the ko.computed. If I remove the throttle this doesn't happen.

Has anyone come across this behavior before?

Comment: Please clarify: what does "they" refer to in "even though *they* are not bound to any observable" and "if I touch the screen then *they* will reappear"?

Comment: Hi Tim. What "they" means is that there is some HTML (like a div containing hard coded text) which is not bound using Knockout. When I add a new action to the observable array then the UI will update but there are some sections like the div with hard coded text will disappear for seemingly no reason. It will reappear when I touch the screen